# Cannot write.csv() without specifying full path

Tags: r

I have found that it was impossible for my R to write a .csv file into a sub-directory of my current working directory unless I specify the full path to the function.

For example, let's say for short I have a dataframe object named `x`. The following code will not work and will produce a "no such file or directory" error:

```
write.csv(x, '/data/my_file.csv')
```

There is already an existing folder called data in my working directory. The following code will work:

```
target_dir <- paste0(getwd(), '/data/my_file.csv')
write.csv(x, target_dir)
```

I'm not from a background of computer science or engineering, but in my head with both codes I'm telling the R to write the file to the exact same location. It would be great if someone could offer a simple solution i.e. to make the code above more streamlined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `write.csv(x, './data/my_file.csv')` (a dot before the path) work instead?

Comment: in addition to Friede's comment: add the "here-dot" *or* skip the leading slash: `write.csv(x, 'data/my_file.csv')`

Comment: Consider also the OS-agnostic `file.path` which avoids slashes and even `paste0`: `write.csv(x, file.path("data", "my_file.csv"))`

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contribute to comments here below, with such elegant solution! I think in the past I didn't add the slash line and it worked, but I simply did not know why and the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The `here` package is a great solution to this - it creates full paths relative to a fixed directory (usually the working directory). So one way to get consistent results would be:

```r
library(here)
read.csv(here("data", "my_file.csv"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This could be handy tool in managing very complicated directory pathway. Will consider using this package in the future.

Comment: I love it personally. Almost all my work starts with `library(here)` and [`library(fs)`](https://fs.r-lib.org/) - the latter is well worth looking into if you're interested in consistently named, vectorized functions for navigating files and paths etc.